# MacTex problem - 'pdflatex does not exist' error

Tags: pdftex, latexdiff

I had a version of MacTex 2014. I needed to use `latexdiff` but this latter command did not work on a terminal. So I installed `latexdiff` as a package from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff?lang=en), by using its make file.

After this installation I could not compile latex anymore. I get the following error message:

```
/usr/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. TeXShop is a front end for TeX, 
but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not
 installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to 
http://tug.org/mactex and follow the instructions to install MacTeX or BasicTeX.
```

I have tried to locate pdf latex on my Mac terminal typing 'locate pdflatex'. I get several paths for directories. The relevant ones seems to be:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex
/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex
```

So I tried to change the path settings in TexShop preferences. I tried to change `/usr/texbin` with either of the two paths above, without the 'pdflatex part', just the directory. The error persists.

I tried to manually delete all the TeX files on my machine and to re-install MacTeX. The error persists.

When I type `which pdflatex` or `which latex` on a terminal a get nothing, an empty line, even after re-installation of MacTex.

How to solve this? Any advice is highly appreciated. 
Thanks beforehand

---

Thanks for your replies!

1) My MacOS's version is 10.9.5

2) when I type `echo $PATH` I get: `/Users/my_name/anaconda3/bin:/Users/my_name/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/abin:/usr/local/fsl/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

3) "Path setting" in TeXShop preferences is by default `/usr/texbin` but I have tried to changed it to the other two paths listed in my previous post and it doesn't work.

4) My TexShop version is 3.77

I have tried to update MacTex2017. My MacOS's version is supposed to be too old for that, but I have installed anyway and the installation went trough, the problem persists though.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some additional information:  1) What’s your MacOS’s version?  2) What reply do you get if you type `echo $PATH` on the command line?  3) Look at the TeXShop Preferences window: the Engine tab has a panel named “Path Setting”, which in turn has a subpanel labeled “(pdf)TeX (default: <something>)”; what’s this <something> in your case?

Comment: I forgot to ask: what version of TeXShop have you got?

Comment: Any chance you could update your TeX distribution to MacTeX2017?

Comment: The reply you get from `echo $PATH$` is not as it should be.  Please check the following:  1) Does a symbolic link named `/Library/TeX/texbin` exist on your system?  2) If so, what destination does it point to?  3) Does a file named `/etc/paths.d/TeX` exist on your system?  4) If so, what are its contents?

Comment: thanks for all your replies! I have edited my previous post with the additional information that you asked me.

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED - I have updated my MacOS to the latest version and now `/Library/TeX/texbin` appears in my $PATH. I have also updated MacTex to its latest 2017 version. Typing `locate pdflatex` on my terminal I find `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-darwin` among other directories. I have changed `Library/TeX/texbin` in TeXShop preferences, engine tab, with `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-darwin` and it now compiles.

Thanks for all the help and replies!

Comment: What does `which pdflatex` return. I'd expect /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex` unless you manually added that `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-darwin` to the PATH yourself. The advantage of using /Library/TeX/texbin is that you can use TeX Live Utility (supplied by MacTeX in `Applications/TeX`) to change the active TeX Distribution so you can have multiple distributions. This will only work if you DON'T prepend that `/usr/local/...` directory to PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I once confronted with this problem with a little bit different environment. This problem raised after I upgrade the MacTeX and my OS had been updated to Mojave previously. It seems **the reason is that the directory of the engine has been changed in this MacTeX upgrade** and what I did to solve it is to change the engine directory to the right one.

Pretty simple: use Terminal, go to the `/Library/TeX`, can see there is two sub-directory: `universal-darwin` and `x86_64-darwin`. I choose the latter one as the final solution as my Mac is based on x86 chips. Thus, the final right directory would be `/Library/TeX/bin/x86_64-darwin`.

Go to the TeXShop’s preference. Go to the ‘engine’. Change it.

Hope this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (a mac user), running MikTexConsole was the only way to resolve (modify environment variable PATH, https://miktex.org/howto/modify-path) it, 
https://miktex.org/download

Comment: It seems they hafve MacTeX (which installs TeX Live) not MikTeX.