# Latex error: could not start the command

Tags: errors, texmaker

I run into this problem after I upgraded my mac system:

Error : could not start the command : "/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode

My mac is Mojave (Version 10.14.4), 
Texmaker version is 5.0.3

Does anyone have the same problem? How to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Texmaker gives an error: could not start the command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126510/texmaker-gives-an-error-could-not-start-the-command)

Comment: This issue is usually defining  the path to tex such that from any command line /terminal app you get a response My experience is windows and you state mac is the issue so need to use `which` or `locate` to check the exact location of pdfLaTeX then add that folder to the places where apps are to be found although a diferent set-up the principle is universal so this may give hints https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393593/mactex-problem-pdflatex-does-not-exist-error/457416#457416